# diffrence between mlx90614 and mlx90616 infrared sensors

Tags: i2c, infrared

I test my code with mlx90614 but with mlx90616 the ambient and object temperature almost same. anybody have this problem. what's the solution?
i test these code on lpc1768 with smbus protocol.
excuse for my english

Comment: [Can this post on EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193602/mlx90616-infra-red-temperature-sensor-problem) offer any insights to your problem with the MLX90616 sensor?

Comment: I guess this is a programming question, since you mentioned code, but I doubt anyone can answer based on this amount of information unless they ran into exactly the same problem. I suggest you give more details. Imagine you’re a random person on SO and need the problem explained to you. Write it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. After carefully reading the datasheet it is clear it needs to be calibrated (how, I'm not sure just yet). It's frustrating because Melexis will not provide technical support unless you're buying 10k+, and are very vague about their "calibration software".

> The ambient temperature sensor in the MLX90616 is calibrated in the
>   factory... The sensor-lens combination temperature measurement has to
>   be calibrated by the customer.

I spent a couple weeks before I realized the reason it was not working, was because it was not calibrated. The output appears to simply be the ambient temperature!

If you read the calibration coefficient register 0x0F you'll see that it is 0x0020.